# My value is in an avocado

Tags: riddle

> I watched a video
>
> And now I feel like an idiot
>
> They said a very large number
>
> Was an avocado number
>
> This many apples of origins
>
> Would wait to be one lamb
>
> They said twelve barb ins
>
> Was twelve dimes of avocados value in
>
> They said a hole of iron
>
> would weigh more than 50 holes of hydrogen
>
> Now dear reader
>
> I, confused as you here,
>
> Wish for you to tell me
>
> The number described for thee

Hint:

> Well you can guess by now that it's more or less horribly misspelled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's:

> Avogadro's number, $6.022\times10^{23}$

*I watched a video

And now I feel like an idiot*

> As best I can tell, this is just an intro with no other hints.

*They said a very large number

Was an avocado number*

> The first misspelling of "Avogadro": avocado; it also happens to be a very large number.

*This many apples of origins
Would wait to be one lamb*

> As ffao points out, one mol of hydrogen ("this many *atoms* of *hydrogen*") would be one *gram*.

*They said twelve barb ins
Was twelve dimes of avocados value in*

> Carbon-12 is the basis for the unit of mols, so 12 mols of carbon (144 grams) has 12 times Avogadro's number of atoms.

*They said a hole of iron
would weigh more than 50 holes of hydrogen*

> Substitution of "hole" for "mole" makes this stanza true.

*Now dear reader

I, confused as you here,

Wish for you to tell me

The number described for thee*

> As best I can tell, this is simply an outro with no other hints.

Comment: Gah, I was just about to get this.

Comment: @Deusovi Ninja'd! Mwahaha.

Comment: For the unexplained line: a mole of hydrogen atoms is one gram?

Comment: @ffao Oh, of course, can't believe I missed that. Thanks!